# Unexpected reserved word error while testing using wallaby

Tags: typescript, wallaby.js

In my test file where I have written test cases, I have imported a typescript file like below:

```
import {rootReducer} from "../src/reducers/rootReducer";
```

In rootReducer.ts I have imported another typescript file like below:

```
import taskReducer from "./taskReducer.ts";
```

Then it shows the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
at src/reducers/rootReducer.ts:7
```

Both rootReducer.ts and taskReducer.ts come under folder /src/reducers

No failing tests if you remove '.ts' from import statement, but throws error in browser. The app won't run then

The wallaby configuration is as below:

```
module.exports = function (wallaby) {

    return {
        files: [
            'src/*.ts',
            'src/**/*.ts'
        ],

        tests: [
            'test/*Test.ts'
        ],

        testFramework: "mocha",

        env: {
            type: 'node'
        },

        compilers: {
            '**/*.ts': wallaby.compilers.typeScript({
                /* 1 for CommonJs*/
                module: 1
            })
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: are you sure this isn't because you are lacking { } in the 2nd import? it looks like a syntax error.

Comment: I had tried adding {} in 2nd import. still shows same error. I guess its something I missed in wallaby configuration, because when I remove the extension '.ts', then there is no wallaby error

Comment: You need to remove `.ts` from import, otherwise you're just loading your TypeScript file as JavaScript, hence the error.

Comment: If I remove    .ts from import, the browser will read its    js file instead of    ts which cause some issues and the app won't work in browser. Is there any way where I can make it both work in wallaby as well as in browser?

Comment: I'm not sure why do you need to load ts instead of js in browser, your build process/module bundler should take care of correctly compiling things for your browser. Anyway, please create a sample repository demonstrating your issue, happy to look into it and help.

Comment: @ArtemGovorov  The repo url 
https://github.com/AmalaLiza/task-tracker

Answer (score 3):

Your statement:

```
import taskReducer from "./taskReducer.ts";
```

Should either be:

```
// Import just taskReducer from this module
import {taskReducer} from "./taskReducer";
```

Or:

```
// Import the whole module and call it taskReducer
import * as taskReducer from "./taskReducer";
```

Comment: Tried both these. Still shows same error. If I remove the extension '.ts', wallaby doesn't show any error. But browser throws error and app won't work

Comment: @DixyXavier you shouldn't need the .ts file.. the module loader should load the .js file at rune time. :-/

Comment: If I remove .ts from import, the browser will read its js file instead of ts which cause some issues and the app won't work in browser. Is there any way where I can make it both work in wallaby as well as in browser?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not in wallaby.js, but in your webpack config. To enable requiring files without specifying the extension, you must add a resolve.extensions parameter specifying which files webpack searches for:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    // you can now require('file') instead of require('file.ts')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts', '.tsx'] 
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you Artem. You are always my saviour :)